# Set background image for list

Tags: jquery, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I am happy with the lists I have so far. However I feel that I could do something groundbreaking. I would like to set a background image (that's the only way I thought), so that every `li` gets displayed in the corresponding line of the image. Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/h7gxpqn0/18/) which doesn't seem to be good.

The CSS is:

```
ol {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url("http://pixelbrush.ru/uploads/posts/2013-01/1359314378_0001-2.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Notice that the image can be changed if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Suggestion:** Give a thought to moving away from jQuery-UI. I am not saying the library is bad but it has a lot of such built-in behavior which you are wanting to override. Hence writing custom styles from scratch would be far more easier for you than overriding multiple such jQuery UI styles.

The way you had added the `background-image` was not incorrect but more specific selectors within the library were applying background & border colors to the `li` elements above the `ol`. Because of this they end up hiding the image that you had added. To overcome it, apply the following settings:

- Set the `background` of the `li` and `a` elements inside the `ol` to transparent using a more specific selector than the one used by the library. Also, since the background image you are trying to use is not straight, the borders would look like they are flowing outside the pad and hence nullify them also.

  ```
  .ui-page-theme-a .ui-block-a ol li.ui-bar-inherit, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-block-a ol li a.ui-btn{
    background: transparent; /* set background of the lis to transparent */
    border-color: transparent; /* set border color to transparent */
  }
  ```
- Set the `padding-top` of the `ol` element such that there is a gap between the small gap after which the contents start. This prevents the header (Europe) coming on top of the clip.

  ```
  .ui-page-theme-a .ui-block-a ol.ui-listview-inset{
    padding-top: 3em; /* adding some padding-top to ol to make header come where we want it to */
  }
  ```
- Finally, set the `background-size` as `cover` for the parent `ol` instead of `contain` Cover means take up the entire width and height of the container.

  ```
  ol {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url("http://pixelbrush.ru/uploads/posts/2013-01/1359314378_0001-2.jpg");
    background-size: cover ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  ```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h7gxpqn0/19/)

Comment: I see your point Harry. Maybe that's why I got a downvote. In my application, the number of players shall vary, from 0 to 12. Is it possible to make the image adjust to that number? Or setting 12 "non-visible" default players and make one visible when a real player is added?

Comment: @gsamaras: That's a bit sad mate. Downvoting because a person is using a library is not right in my opinion. Anyways can't do much about such things. Coming to the image itself, it would auto adjust but having the clip on top and the perspective (or slanted inwards) nature of the image would cause some trouble with alignment. You may have to use a straighter looking one with no clip.

Comment: @gsamaras: For example, with a different background image, you could assign the `ol` a fixed height and width to produce something like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7gxpqn0/20/).

Comment: +1 to your top answer for being so good and polite Harry, that's sweet. If I find a picture that is close to the one's we use in football then I will make the change in my actual application. The picture you are using reminds me of the agenda of my mother. :)

Comment: @gsamaras: It reminded me of Louis van Gaal's scribble pad and that's why I picked it up :P Btw, if you manage to find a suitable one and are unable to adapt it then feel free to ping me here :)

Comment: Oh good point! However, I will look for other pictures, because the image is not clear (because of the stretching). Maybe if I find another picture, this will work..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88940/discussion-between-gsamaras-and-harry).

Comment: @gsamaras: It's almost midnight here and I'm leaving mate. Lets discuss later :)